# .NET Web Browser Control - SaveAs Event

Tags: .net, events, browser, savefiledialog

Does anybody know if you can access the SaevFileDialog control that's used by the WebBrowser control? Once somebody saves the webpage being displayed I need to catch where the files have been created; however I can't seem to find any events/members that allow me access to that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you cannot access the Save As dialog that is provided by the WebBrowser control.

I'm not sure if you're writing a WinForms application or an ASP.Net application, but since you're using a WebBrowser control, I'm assuming that you're writing a WinForms application in which you want to show some HTML content.

In this case, if I wanted the end user to save to a specific location on their disk, I would provide my own Save button and in the button's Click event, I would read the text of the HTML displayed in the browser control (which can be done easily) and pass it to a System.IO.StreamWriter to save the contents to that file.

If you want to have the customers select where to save, then use a SaveFileDialog of your own in the button's Click event.

Comment: I thought about doing that; the problem is that I need to save all of the images as the standard webbrowser save dialog saves them; it seems a bit of a shame to have to  reproduce functionality that already exists simply because the webbrowser control doesn't allow access to its dialog events.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first post in that you should create your own save button and stream the html document to file. This provides much more control. Alternatively, you can use [WATIN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) for all sorts of cool stuff, including managing file download dialog boxes and events.